# how to insert a dictionary with sqlsoup

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy, sqlsoup

I am trying to insert a dictionary with sqlsoup.  Unfortuntely this doesn't work:

```
db.blah_table.insert({"blah_field" : "blah_value"})
```

it gives me an error

```
TypeError: insert() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

the update for sqlsoup works fine.  I really don't want to break this up into

```
db.blah_table.insert(blah_field = "blah_value")
```

which works as well.  help!

Comment: You are trying to insert the dictionary or key value pairs in the dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, you can pass a dictionary as *keyword arguments* to any function by using the `**` argument packing syntax.

If you have a dictionary `arguments` defined as:

```
arguments = {'blah_field': 'blah_value'}
```

You can call `db.blah_table.insert` with that dictionary as keyword arguments like this:

```
db.blah_table.insert(**arguments)
```

Under the hood this is equivalent to:

```
db.blah_table.insert(blah_field=blah_value)
```

As an aside, while `**` can unpack named arguments from a dictionary, a single `*` can be used to unpack positional arguments from a list or tuple.